# Custom form field not showing validation message

Tags: magento2, forms, magento-2.2.5, form-validation, custom-field

I have created one custom form and implemented magento validation. Magento validation works for all fields but message of one field is not displaying. I have added datepicker in this field.

Below is the code of my field:

```
<div class="field field-name-reward_date required">
<label class="label required" for="reward_date"><span>Reward Distribution Date</span></label>
<div class="control date">
    <input type="text" name="reward_date" class="input-text _has-datepicker mage-error" data-validate="{'required':true, 'validate-reward-date':true}" id="dp1544438747646" aria-required="true" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="true">
    <span class="calender-icon glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</div>
```

It shows red border when field is not valid, but it not show the message.
[image]

Please let me know if anyone can help.

Comment: Hi Gaurav facing the same issue do you got any solution for this

Comment: It was because of datetimepicker which I was using here. So I replaced it with datetimerangepicker with single datepicker.

Answer (score 1):

add billow JS script to your form

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'mage/mage',
        'mage/validation'
    ], function($){

            var dataForm = $('#form-id');
            dataForm.mage('validation', {
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            });

});
</script>
```